# How to get sublime text 3 to open independent UI instances

Tags: linux, sublimetext3

I am using sublime text 3 build 3059 in Linux. I open the UI using the command line with -new-window option and point to a file or a directory. I may do this multiple times so several UI instances will be open simultaneously. I would like separate instances of the UI to act independent of each other. Using the --new-window option gets me close but I have found that closing one instance of the UI using ctlr+q / menu->file->quit will close all open UI instances. This is not the case when I close using the X button in the upper right corner which only closes the current instances. This can be painful when there are open instances located in various virtual desktops. Then when you open a file for a quick edit and close it using ctrl+q, all UI instances are closed. This not a good user experience. Does anyone know of an option that would allow me to have ctrl+q close only the current UI instance? My real need is to have the instances to act independently.

BTW, I have found sublime text 2 post that answer this question but sublime text 3 seems to behavior differently in this regard.

Comment: Ctrl+q quits the application.  You are probably looking for "close window"

Comment: I have seen this question asked multiple times and no answer, only workarounds. In my case, I am running two window managers in parallel and would like sublime in each so I need two instances, there is no other way. Wish me luck!

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> shortcut is the shortcut to exit the application and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> is the shortcut to close window. This is simply a usability thing and it's somewhat a convention used in may more applications other than Sublime Text.

The <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> shortcut is not mapped in ST settings rather is built-in for Linux version of ST. The OS X version allows remapping this through it's system hotkey settings but not the Linux one.

Thus I suggest simply trying to retrain yourself and use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> instead.